# ValueError: Mountpoint must not contain a space. (Colab)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, mount

Here is my code in google colab:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('content/drive/My Drive/ML')
```

I have a path which contains space symbol and I get this error:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py in mount(mountpoint, force_remount, timeout_ms)
     89 
     90   if ' ' in mountpoint:
---> 91     raise ValueError('Mountpoint must not contain a space.')
     92 
     93   mountpoint = _os.path.expanduser(mountpoint)

> ValueError: Mountpoint must not contain a space.

I have tried drive.mount('content/drive/My\ Drive/ML') and this doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run instead:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

The leading `/` is important. Once mounted at `/content/drive`, you'll see `My Drive/ML` in that directory. `/content/drive` is the directory path on your local machine. `My Drive/ML` is the path within your Drive. (`My Drive` distinguishes your Drive from Team drives.)

Comment: What if I want to mount that folder directly?

Comment: There are good reasons to not give colab read/write access to your entire google drive.

Answer (score 15):

1. Mount at `/content/drive`

   ```
   from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('/content/drive')
   ```
2. Change directory using cd command

   ```
   cd 'drive/My Drive'
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated button in the sidebar that pastes the necessary cell to mount the drive:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/gdrive")
```

Please note about **gdrive**.

It will then ask for authentication code and once you give the same, the drive will be mounted successfully.

**Mounted at /content/gdrive**

Once the drive is mounted, you can navigate just like on your local machine.

Answer (score -2):

Try this way it's working.

```
cd 'My Drive'/
```